# What's the definition of "qualification effort"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I've mostly seen it in some legal or related texts, but didn't manage to find any definition.

Sample:

> It jeopardises investment in
>   research and innovation, devalues intelligence and the **qualification**
>   **effort**, encourages organised crime and clearly weakens the rule of
>   law. That is why combating counterfeiting must be an absolute
>   imperative for all EU Member States.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that there, it means - loosely - *the effort people go to, to gain qualifications.*

The passage appears to come from a Euro-debate in Strasbourg in 2008, in which MEP Francisco Assis (PSE) spoke about the perils of counterfeiting.

The full text (http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20081217+ITEMS+DOC+XML+V0//EN&language=EN) shows that either the English version was made by a poor translator, or Assis was a poor speaker with poor subject knowledge or both.

Given that background, doesn't *qualification effort* seem a lot less specific or meaningful than it might?